# AutoIT script/UDF to interface with Amazon S3 API

Tags: amazon-s3, autoit

I'm trying to make an AutoIT script interface with the Amazon S3 API. I've been trying both SOAP and REST, although no success.

This is the SOAP code I'm working with (modified example from Ptrex on the AutoIT forums), however I get the following response:
"soapenv:Client.badRequest Missing SOAPAction header"

To be honest, the code doesn't make that much sense to me and I'm really just tinkering around.

Any examples or pointers to get me going in the right direction on how to properly interface with the Amazon S3 API would be greatly appreciated!

```
; Initialize COM error handler
$oMyError = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error","MyErrFunc")

$objHTTP = ObjCreate("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
$objReturn = ObjCreate("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0")

$strEnvelope = '<soap:envelope xmlns:soap="urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:soap.v1">' & _
'<soap:header></soap:header>' & _
'<soap:body>' & _
'<ListAllMyBuckets xmlns="http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/2006-03-01">' & _
  '<AWSAccessKeyId>MYACCESSKEYID</AWSAccessKeyId>' & _
  '<Timestamp>2006-03-01T12:00:00.183Z</Timestamp>' & _
  '<Signature>MYSECRETSIGNATURE</Signature>' & _
'</ListAllMyBuckets>' & _
'</soap:body>' & _
'</soap:envelope>'

; Set up to post to our local server
$objHTTP.open ("post", "https://s3.amazonaws.com/soap", False)

; Set a standard SOAP/ XML header for the content-type
$objHTTP.setRequestHeader ("xmlns:aws",  "http://security.amazonaws.com/doc/2007-01-01/")

 Make the SOAP call
$objHTTP.send ($strEnvelope)

; Get the return envelope
$strReturn = $objHTTP.responseText

; ConsoleWrite("Debug : "& $strReturn & @CR & @CR)

; Load the return envelope into a DOM
$objReturn.loadXML ($strReturn)

ConsoleWrite("Return of the SOAP Msg : " & @CR & $objReturn.XML & @CR & @CR)

; Query the return envelope
$strQuery = "SOAP:Envelope/SOAP:Body/ListAllMyBuckets"

$dblTax = $objReturn.selectSingleNode($strQuery)
$Soap = $objReturn.Text

MsgBox(0,"SOAP Response",$Soap)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you out but from the autoit part everything works well The answer you get from amazon 'soapenv:Client.badRequest Missing SOAPAction header' means what it actually says something worng with your request. -namely: Missing SOAPAction header

What you get was indeed a response but an error response from the server. I suggest trying to rewrite the request

I found the most relevant description here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/2008-01-01/SQSDeveloperGuide/index.html?MakingRequests_MakingSOAPRequestsArticle.html